# Paint with soft brush (logic)

Tags: unity, textures

During the last few days I was coding a painting behavior for a game am working on, and am currently in a very advanced phase, I can say that I have 90% of the work done and working perfectly, now what I need to do is being able to draw with a "soft brush" cause for now it's like am painting with "pixel style" and that was totally expected because that's what I wrote.

My current goal consist of using this solution :

1. Import a brush texture
2. Create an array that contain all The alpha values of that texture
3. When drawing use the array elements in order to define the new pixels alpha

And this is my code to do that (it's not very long, there is too much comments)

```
//The main painting method
//theObject     = the object to be painted
//tmpTexture    = the object current texture
//targetTexture = the new texture 
void paint (GameObject theObject, Texture2D tmpTexture, Texture2D targetTexture)
{
    //x and y are 2 floats from another class
    //they store the coordinates of the pixel 
    //that get hit by the RayCast
    int x = (int)(coordinates.pixelPos.x);
    int y = (int)(coordinates.pixelPos.y);

    //iterate through a block of pixels that goes fro
    //Y and X and go #brushHeight Pixels up
    // and #brushWeight Pixels right
    for (int tmpY = y; tmpY<y+brushHeight; tmpY++) {
        for (int tmpX = x; tmpX<x+brushWidth; tmpX++) {
           //check if the current pixel is different from the target pixel
           if (tmpTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY) != targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY)) {
               //create a temporary color from the target pixel at the given coordinates
                Color tmpCol = targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY);
                //change the alpha of that pixel based on the brush alpha
                //myBrushAlpha is a 2 Dimensional array that contain
                //the different Alpha values of the brush
                //the substractions are to keep the index in range
                if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
                    tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
                }
                //set the new pixel to the current texture
                tmpTexture.SetPixel (tmpX, tmpY, tmpCol);
            } 
        }
    }
    //Apply 
    tmpTexture.Apply ();
    //change the object main texture 
    theObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = tmpTexture;
}
```

Now the fun (and bad) part is the code did exactly what I asked for, but by asking to draw anytime with the brush alpha I found myself create a very weird effect which is decreasing the alpha value of an "old" pixel, so I tried to fix that by adding an `if` statement that check if the current alpha of the pixel is less than the equivalent brush alpha pixel, if it is, then augment the alpha to be equal to the brush, and if the pixel alpha is bigger, then keep adding the brush alpha value to it in order to have that "soft brushing" effect, and in code it become this  :

```
if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > tmpCol.a) {
  tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
} else {
  tmpCol.a += myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
}
```

But after I've done that, I got the "pixelized brush" effect back, am not sure but I think maybe it's because I'm making these conditions inside a `for` loop so everything is executed before the end of the current frame so I don't see the effect, could it be that?

Am really lost here and hope that you can put me in the right direction.

Comment: I also tried to break the conditions but still didn't get the willing effect

Comment: I think you are trying to mix two colors, the soft brush and the existing color. To do that compute the weighted average of the colors instead of replacing the RGB values.

Comment: From the looks of it you/we are overriding the textures native alpha value with a constant parameter that is incorrect for the outline.

Comment: Glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer:

After giving it much thought I think you may not be blending the new clor with the existing one.
I took the liberty to modify the code to what might work here:

```
for (int tmpY = y; tmpY<y+brushHeight; tmpY++) {
    for (int tmpX = x; tmpX<x+brushWidth; tmpX++) {
           //No need to check if the current pixel is different from the target pixel
            Color oldCol = tmpTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY);
            Color tmpCol = targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY);
            //change the alpha of that pixel based on the brush alpha
            if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
                tmpCol.a *= myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
            }
            //set the new pixel to the current texture
            double total_alpha = tmpCol.a + oldCol.a;
            tmpCol.a = oldCol.a + (1 - oldCol.a) * tmpCol.a;
            tmpCol.r = (tmpCol.r * tmpCol.a + oldCol.r * oldCol.a) / total_alpha;
            tmpCol.g = (tmpCol.g * tmpCol.a + oldCol.g * oldCol.a) / total_alpha;
            tmpCol.b = (tmpCol.b * tmpCol.a + oldCol.b * oldCol.a) / total_alpha;
            tmpTexture.SetPixel (tmpX, tmpY, tmpCol);
    }
}
```

Old answer:

This piece of code appears to be incorrect.

```
if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > tmpCol.a) {
  tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
} else {
  tmpCol.a += myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
}
```

I believe what you wish to do is mix the color of the brush with the current color of that pixel. It should be something like this:

```
// mba == myBrushAlpha[tmpY - y, tmpX - x]; 

double total_alpha = tmpCol.a + mba.a;
double alpha_result = tmpCol.a + (1 - tmpCol.a) * mba.a;
double red_result = (tmpCol.r * tmpCol.a + mba.r * mba.a) / total_alpha;
double green_result = (tmpCol.g * tmpCol.a + mba.g * mba.a) / total_alpha;
double blue_result = (tmpCol.b * tmpCol.a + mba.b * mba.a) / total_alpha;

tmpCol.a = alpha_result; // Assuming you will set the color to tmpCol.
tmpCol.r = red_result; 
tmpCol.g = green_result; 
tmpCol.b = blue_result;
```

I also notice this:

```
if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
    tmpCol.a = myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
}
```

It looks like it might have been supposed to be something along the lines:

```
if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
    tmpCol.a *= myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly :D !! thank you!! but for some reason am getting an "outline" effect, something that i never had before, it's like am adding a black contour to the object, any idea why ?

Comment: @alaslipknot Picture please?

Comment: the expected result is suppose to be like this (the pink eye lash) 
[link](http://s20.postimg.org/gi69p2if1/image.png) but instead am getting [this](http://s20.postimg.org/nzfh4a7y5/image.png) the outline is clear but that black part on the left is also a weird result cause it comes there when am drawing in an "empty" place, to better understand this i need to tell you a little bit more about how i draw, in fact, i don't use "direct" color, instead i have many textures with same size but different colors and effect and when i draw i just call pixels that are in the same position,

Comment: from the new texture so normally the "empty" pixels are the same in both textures and should always be empty (it worked before) thank you

Comment: @alaslipknot - the images look very pretty - 
So maybe black is always supposed to be transparent and now you/we are overriding it's value with the alpha setting of the brush? Maybe there is an inherit alpha value embedded at the texture? Perhaps you need to multiply the alpha used by the texture alpha value?

Comment: thank you :) , and yup i think that's exactly what happened cause after i removed this condition `if (tmpTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY) != targetTexture.GetPixel (tmpX, tmpY))` i was able to redraw the whole texture even the transparent area which is something that i didn't had before, [image](http://s20.postimg.org/4knzww62l/image.png) am going to try to solve this but now with always keeping the black transparent, cause i may need to draw with black some time

Comment: You need an alpha value for the texture instead of relying on rgb to control the transparency. I think it is possible, I misunderstood your code originally, you may actually want to do the weighted average with the existing pixel in the image your are painting on.

Comment: I mean here: tmpTexture.SetPixel (tmpX, tmpY, tmpCol); You may want to get the existing pixel and blend with it with weighted average.

Comment: that is what am trying to do now, thnx :) !!

Comment: ps: is it normal to have my textures in the inspector like [link](http://s20.postimg.org/m5w12hozh/tex.png) cause they are all transparent pngs, they become like that right after i transformed them into Advanced textures in order to check Read/Write enabled

Comment: @alaslipknot I updated the answer, try it out.

Comment: now it's like am drawing with fire :p 
[link](http://s20.postimg.org/vrplisg59/image.png) 
it's because of this 
`if (myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a > 0) {
                tmpCol.a *= myBrushAlpha [tmpY - y, tmpX - x].a;
            }` 
i tried += instead of *= , the result was less "violent" but still not perfect

Comment: oh and the "soft brush" effect is gone too

Comment: Yeah, it appears tmp texture does not contain the current texture? Maybe that is why the result is very random.

Comment: no am sure it does, i did it when i call the painting method, plus for checking i added this to the method (before the for loop) 
`tmpTexture =(Texture2D) theObject.renderer.material.mainTexture ;`

Comment: also it's not "random" it's indeed drawing with the "correct" color but somehow you made some plasma effect or something

Comment: what is the vale range for tmoCol.a ,r ,g ,b? Is it 0-255 or 0.0-1.0?

Comment: it's 0.0-1.0, by the way, i changed all the double to float cause unity Color take 4 floats as parameters and all of them are between 0.0-1.0

Comment: Finally it worked :D !!! 
am going to edit your post in order to choose it as the correct answer, you're going to be surprised when you read it, i always found this kind of mistakes super funny cause the solution was **always** there, the only problem is the order of the execution all i had to do is make a little change to your last update, so instead of increasing the alpha,  we just have to check after these calculation if the current pixel.a is superior of the target.a, if so, make it equal to the target, again, thank you very much !!! i really apreaciate your help, thank you

Comment: I rejected your edit, it was a massive addition to the existing answer; that's not how edits should work. Either post a new answer with that information or make only the edits necessary to transform an answer to an improved version. Also, please avoid having extended discussions in the comments in the future; that is not what they are for and the need for them suggests a "debug my code" problem that is off-topic here. If you need to have extended discussions, use [chat].